# Gygabyte motherboard doesn't power off

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bios

I have a home-made pc with a Gygabyte G1 Sniper.3 motherboard (BIOS version F7) and Windows 7 64bit. It has been working flawlessly for almost two years but in the last three weeks it seems to have lost the ability to properly power off itself: when I shutdown Windows, the operating system actually shuts down, but the pc is still on.
If I - say - unplug the power cord, pc does not start properly (after plugging back the power cord, of course) but hangs in the Bios screen: I have to remove the CR2032 battery (I have already changed the battery, too) and finally pc turns on, asks me to configure BIOS and only then O.S. starts properly.
Any suggestions about causes and remedies?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you wait some time before shutting it down manually?
I've had this issue with my Gigabyte MB as well, but it seemed that it was still cooling down the CPU and harddrives.
After the cooling down (which took 2 minutes), the system turned off.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer.
I am not totally sure now, but I think I have been waiting for more than two minutes: I am sure I waited for 10 orb 15 minutes, but it was before I cahnged the battery.
But what beats me is that it seems to loose the BIOS settings: I was ready for some Windows issue, not for BIOS issues.
Anyway, I'll retry again tonight and will let you know.
Thanks again

Comment: Losing your BIOS settings usually means one of three things: Either your BIOS battery is end-of-life, it is not properly connected, or there is a component in your PC not turning off that drains its power. Do you also lose your BIOS settings if you turn off your PC the hard way, by holding the power button, without removing the power cord? Holding the power button is still always better then unplugging it, since it allows a few microseconds to shut down.

Comment: Changing the battery was my first guess and try: I bought a new one and put it in
Of course my first tries were to shut down Windows normally (i.e.: via Start menu), then I tried to shut it down by pressing the power button (I have configured it to wait for 4 secs before shutting down ). I said "unplug the power cord" only to express more clearly the idea, but of course I never really unplugged brutally the cord :) .
Ahyway, the results were always the same: Bios settings lost, had to remove and replace battery and then reconfigure Bios.